# Change MySQL data received from sensor

Tags: mysql

I receive data from a Bluetooth sensor via an ESP32 which then sends data to raspberry pi via API to MySQL. I receive the temperature on the rpi, but as 1230 instead of 12.30. Is it possible to change it in MySQL, if yes, how?

Comment: Isn't it just a basic math???  Divide by 100.

Comment: Would you mind accepting my answer if it solved your need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`select 1230/100` will return 12.3

Do the following if you want two decimal points:

```
select format(temperature/100, 2)
from table1
```

To use this, you may want to create a view that has this calcuated field in it. You would then use the view instead of the table in your API.

```
create view view1 as (select format(temperature/100, 2) 
                      from table1);
```

[You can see how it works in Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/757395/1).